# How to find the total playing time per day for all the users in my sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table which contains following columns

```
userid, 
game, 
gameStarttime datetime, 
gameEndtime datetime, 
startdate datetime,
currentdate datetime
```

I can retrieve all the playing times but I want to count the total playing time per DAY and 0 or null if game not played on a specific day.

Comment: Add some sample data and expected output

Comment: So your main problem is that you want to have a record per day from min(gameStarttime) till max(gameEndtime), but don't get the days where noone played? Or is your problem simply that you don't know how to calculate the difference between gameStarttime and gameEndtime? It would be good if you showed your query, so we can see how far you got.

Comment: My problem is to correctly calculate the game time of a person per day from start date till today.

Comment: This sounds like you want a /played feature like a popular MMORPG which calculates how many days and hours you actual played time is in-game. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `DATEDIFF` to do the time calculations. Your requirements are not very clear, but it should work for whatever you're looking to do.

Your end result would probably look something like this:

```
SELECT
    userid, 
    game,
    DATEDIFF(SS, gameStarttime, gameEndtime) AS [TotalSeconds]
FROM [source]
GROUP BY
    userid,
    game
```

In the example query above, the `SS` counts the seconds between the 2 dates (assuming both are not null). If you need just minutes, then `MI` will provide the total minutes. However, I imagine total seconds is best so that you can convert to whatever unit of measure you need accurate, such as hours that might be "1.23" or something like that.

Again, most of this is speculation based on assumptions and what you seem to be looking for. Hope that helps.

MSDN Docs for DATEDIFF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

You may also look up DATEPART if you want the minutes and seconds separately.

**UPDATED BASED ON FEEDBACK**

The query below breaks out the hour breakdowns by day, splits time across multiple days, and shows "0" for days where no games are played. Also, for your output, I have to assume you have a separate table of users (so you can show users who have no time in your date range).

```
-- Define start date
DECLARE @BeginDate DATE = '4/21/2015'

-- Create sample data
DECLARE @Usage TABLE (
    userid int,
    game nvarchar(50),
    gameStartTime datetime,
    gameEndTime datetime
)
DECLARE @Users TABLE (
    userid int
)
INSERT @Users VALUES (1)
INSERT @Usage VALUES
    (1, 'sample', '4/25/2015 10pm', '4/26/2015 2:30am'),
    (1, 'sample', '4/22/2015 4pm', '4/22/2015 4:30pm')

-- Generate list of days in range
DECLARE @DayCount INT = DATEDIFF(DD, @BeginDate, GETDATE()) + 1
;WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT TOP (225) [object_id] FROM sys.all_objects
), [Days] AS (
    SELECT TOP (@DayCount)
        DATEADD(DD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.[object_id]) - 1, @BeginDate) AS [Day]
    FROM CTE x
        CROSS JOIN CTE y
    ORDER BY
        [Day]
)
    SELECT
        [Days].[Day],
        Users.userid,
        SUM(COALESCE(CONVERT(MONEY, DATEDIFF(SS, CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, Usage.gameStartTime) < [Day] THEN [Day] ELSE Usage.gameStartTime END,
            CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, Usage.gameEndTime) > [Day] THEN DATEADD(DD, 1, [Days].[Day]) ELSE Usage.gameEndTime END)) / 3600, 0)) AS [Hours]
    FROM [Days]
        CROSS JOIN @Users Users
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Usage Usage
            ON Usage.userid = Users.userid
                AND [Days].[Day] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, Usage.gameStartTime) AND CONVERT(DATE, Usage.gameEndTime)
    GROUP BY
        [Days].[Day],
        Users.userid
```

The query above yields the output below for the sample data:

```
Day        userid      Hours
---------- ----------- ---------------------
2015-04-21 1           0.00
2015-04-22 1           0.50
2015-04-23 1           0.00
2015-04-24 1           0.00
2015-04-25 1           2.00
2015-04-26 1           2.50
2015-04-27 1           0.00
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for more than that. I have segments of playing time for each user. In each day a person playing start time and playing end time is recorded. From that I want to see how much a person played per day. E.g he might have played for 2 hours on one day, 10 hours on another day and 0 hours on some other day

Comment: So are you looking for a record for each day they did AND did not play? For example, do you need a record by user and game on the day they played 0 hours? Also, for your use case over 10pm to 2am, do you care if that's 4 hours on day 1 or should it be 2 hours on each day?

Comment: yes, and if played then for how long. Both will do.

Comment: I think it should be like if datediff output == 0 than add the same day or add next day.

Comment: Updated answer based on your comments

Comment: Its much complicated than i expected. I am implementing it. I will update you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I dont know how will i use it for multiple users and what is the purpose of top in the query?

Comment: It should already handle multiple users due to the GROUP BY. The TOP is used as a technique to generate the sequence of dates. That's part of what is challenging about your question. Here's a breakdown of other techiques: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76383/discussion-between-asbat-and-jason-w).

Comment: Hi, can you please have a look of my question and give suggestion. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208532/how-can-i-sum-values-per-day-and-then-plot-them-on-calendar-from-start-date-to-l/32209611#32209611

Comment: @asbat - I must not understand your referenced question. It would seem that my answer here would solve that problem as well. It generates the dates within the range (BeginDate to today, which can easily be converted into BeginDate to EndDate). It uses 0 when no matches are found, and already handles cases across multiple days.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited my sql on sql fiddle and I think this might get you what you asked for. to me it looks a little more simple then the answer you've accepted.

```
DECLARE @FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime
SELECT @Fromdate = MIN(StartDate), @ToDate = MAX(currentDate)
FROM Games

-- This recursive CTE will get you all dates 
-- between the first StartDate and the last CurrentDate on your table
;WITH AllDates AS(
    SELECT @Fromdate As TheDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TheDate + 1
    FROM   AllDates
    WHERE TheDate + 1 <= @ToDate
)

SELECT UserId, 
       TheDate,
       COALESCE( 
         SUM(
            -- When the game starts and ends in the same date
            CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, GameStartTime, GameEndTime) = 0 THEN
                DATEDIFF(HOUR, GameStartTime, GameEndTime)
            ELSE 
                -- when the game starts in the current date
                CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, GameStartTime, TheDate) = 0 THEN
                    DATEDIFF(HOUR, GameStartTime, DATEADD(Day, 1, TheDate))
                ELSE -- meaning the game ends in the current date
                    DATEDIFF(HOUR, TheDate, GameEndTime)
                END 
            END 
         ), 
       0) As HoursPerDay

FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT UserId, 
      TheDate,
      CASE 
           WHEN CAST(GameStartTime as Date) = TheDate 
           THEN GameStartTime 
           ELSE NULL 
      END As GameStartTime, -- return null if no game started that day
      CASE 
           WHEN CAST(GameEndTime as Date) = TheDate 
           THEN GameEndTime 
           ELSE NULL 
           END As GameEndTime -- return null if no game ended that day
      FROM Games CROSS APPLY AllDates -- This is where the magic happens :-)    
      ) InnerSelect
GROUP BY UserId, TheDate
ORDER BY UserId, TheDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[Play with it your self on sql fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1673b/11)

Comment: On checking in fiddle. It is showing records with playtime only. I am looking for the output like above for all users.

Comment: See my edited answer. I must say It's been an interesting challenge, please let me know if I nailed it even if you accepted the other answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right this time. Thanks a lot. Now I have two ways to do it. Lets see which one I pick.

Comment: Great :-) It's been a while since I've done something interesting in sql, thanks for the challenge.

Comment: BTW I want to get the time in seconds because in my short experience of sql I have found that rounding off minutes and hours generate wrong answers when you are adding multiple segments. So its better to get them in seconds and then change them to minutes or hours which is also pointed out by @Jason

Comment: then Simply change the datediffs that uses hours to datediffs that uses seconds: `DATEDIFF(HOUR, GameStartTime, GameEndTime)` should be `DATEDIFF(SECOND, GameStartTime, GameEndTime)`. don't forget to change all of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76430/discussion-between-asbat-and-zohar-peled).

Comment: Kind of busy at work right now, leave a comment here and I'll try to answer as soon as I can

Comment: Can you please check my other question, if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038826/why-the-following-sql-server-query-returns-12-months-data-and-not-14-months-data?noredirect=1#comment51982013_32038826

Comment: Hi, can you please have a look of my question and give suggestion. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208532/how-can-i-sum-values-per-day-and-then-plot-them-on-calendar-from-start-date-to-l/32209611#32209611