# Why the following SQL Server query returns 12 months data and not 14 months data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query which returns data for 12 months. Originally the query was for 14 days and I changed the day to month in `datediff` method to get 14 months data but I am getting only 12 months data. Can anyone please check and see why?

```
Select 'playing' As activity 
--,ad.xDate 
,min(ad.xDate) As xDate
,Isnull(sum(t.TimePerDay),0) As TimePerDay 
From    AllDates As ad With (Nolock) 
Left Join @test As t On ad.xDate = t.date
GROUP BY datepart(Month, ad.xDate)
--ORDER BY YEAR(datepart(Month, ad.xDate)) DESC, MONTH(datepart(Month, ad.xDate)) DESC, DAY(datepart(Month, ad.xDate))
ORDER BY MIN(ad.xDate)
option (maxrecursion 0)
END
```

Comment: And which **version** of SQL Server do you **actually** use? 2005 ? 2008 ? 2008 R2 ? Don't just tag every version you find - please use only the *actual one in use*.

Comment: @Asbat . . . I removed the extraneous SQL Server tags.  Feel free to add the *one* for the database you are actually using.

Comment: @Asbat. The query is quite long - highly likely that most if it is irrelevant to the problem. So this may be more useful to others, please reduce it to the bare minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Can you narrow down the source of the problem? try to see what you get from the cte if you only select from it.

Comment: I am getting data since beginning for the user e.g. from 2013 to date

Comment: start small. write the simplest query you can selecting the data you want. verify min and max ranges of the data are correct, even in excel or looking by eye. Then add each component of the query in one by one, and verify the results at each stage. unless we have all the data and your table structure, it will be very difficult for us to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by both month and year parts of ad.xDate. There are only twelve months of the year and you should be seeing the earliest two (14 - 2) month of your results with totals that are too large because they actually represent a combination of two calendar months.

It worked in your original version because there are more than 14 days in any month. If you tried to extend that old query beyond 31 days (or 28, 29, 30 for some months) then you find the same problem all over again.

```
...
SELECT
    'playing' As activity,
    min(ad.xDate) As xDate, 
    Isnull(sum(t.TimePerDay), 0) As TimePerDay
FROM AllDates As ad Left Outer Join @test As t On ad.xDate = t.date
GROUP BY Year(ad.xDate), Month(ad.xDate) /* <--- change here */
ORDER BY xDate
```

Comment: I have used the same query to get weekly data but I got in to two problems which are beyond my expertise. 1) It shows one week of 6 days and all other of 7 days. 2) At the end of year it lost the sequence and shows 2014-12-28, 01-01-2015, 2015-01-04. Can you please look the following two links and help me out 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083087/why-the-following-query-is-not-splitting-the-weeks-equally-between-the-year-chan

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060149/how-to-get-last-14-weeks-from-the-specific-date-starting-the-week-from-that-spec

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

```
Select  @MaxDate = @MaxDate
,@MinDate = dateadd(Month, (@LastXMonths + 1), @MaxDate)
```

`@LastXMonths = -14` so your `@MinDate` is only 13 months before `@MaxDate`.

Next, this statement:

```
GROUP BY datepart(Month, ad.xDate)
```

It will return a number from 1 to 12 so you will never get any more than 12 months.

### Solution:

Remove the `+1` in the first statement and change the final select to:

```
Select 'playing' As activity 
,ad.xDate 
,Isnull(sum(t.TimePerDay),0) As TimePerDay 
From    AllDates As ad With (Nolock) 
Left Join @test As t On ad.xDate = t.date
GROUP BY ad.xDate
ORDER BY ad.xDate
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: When you go back 13 months you will still cover 14 distinct months when you count them all including the starting month. But you're right about the grouping problem. OP had a working version by days and tried to change it to work with months.