# How to split the weeks equally between the year change

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query worked fine in generating weeks until the year change. As you can see in the generated output (given in the following image) during year change I got a different pattern. Please help. I want equal split of 7 days. At the moment order is the order is not equal as you can see in the output 28/12/2014, 01/01/2015 and 04/01/2015 are in wrong order. Similarly the first difference is not 7 days but 6 days ( from 04/09/2014 to 09/11/2014). I want this to be 7 days to i.e. ( from 03/09/2014 to 09/11/2014)

Comment: WHat do you want it to do?  You might try ISO_WEEK instead of week for datepart.

Comment: I want equal split of 7 days. At the moment order is the order is not equal as you can see in the output 28/12/2014, 01/01/2015 and 04/01/2015 are in wrong order. Similarly the first difference is not 7 days but 6 days ( from 04/09/2014 to 09/11/2014). I want this to be 7 days to i.e. ( from 03/09/2014 to 09/11/2014)

Comment: This question is certainly not a minimal, complete, verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This question seems to have been edited so makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Which day do you want your weeks to start on?

```
GROUP BY datediff(dd, ad.xDate, @MaxDate) / 7
```

EDIT: I think I understand what you're trying to do with the `AllDates` CTE but I can't figure out how it works. Based on what it see it looks like it duplicates the `@MinDate` value as well as pulling out every date prior to `@MaxDate`. My expectation is to see something like this which should take care of your extra day problem. I'm also guessing that your 14-week blocks of weeks are overlapping by a single day.

```
;WITH AllDates AS (
    SELECT xDate FROM AllDates WHERE xDate > @MinDate AND xDate <= @MaxDate
)
```

Comment: instead of this GROUP BY datepart(wk, ad.xDate)

Comment: I did it, one problem solved but one left. The first two dates are not splitted 2014-11-04, 2014-11-05 and then fine for remaining 2014-11-12, 2014-11-19 and so on.

Comment: I think it's because you have an extra day in your range. If you want it to be exactly 14 weeks (or whatever) you'll have to adjust the start or end appropriately.

Comment: I did something similar for months i.e. to complete the week instead of showing 1 2 3 4 5 6 days. I wonder if it is possible here? Actually the date is dynamic so from current date to last 14 days? Can you suggest how can I do it because I have three queries. One show first 14 weeks, Second show next 14 weeks and third shows next 14 weeks from user last update. total 42 weeks data

Comment: Here is what I did with months http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049478/how-can-i-get-the-last-12-months-from-the-current-date-plus-extra-days-till-1st

Answer (score 0):

you could use a cte to generate the 14 weeks

This will generate a table that has the weeks in 7 day increments, regardless of the start date, which you could then use to classify your data:

```
declare @startdate date
set @startdate = '2014-11-13'

;with cte (SOW,EOW,cnt) 
as
    (
    select @startdate as SOW,dateadd(dd,6,@startdate) as EOW, 1 as cnt
    union all
    select dateadd(dd,7,SOW),dateadd(dd,7,EOW),cnt+1
    from cte
    where cnt<14
    )
select * from cte
```

Comment: I am newbie, can you please incorporate it in above query?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099211/how-to-avoid-datepart-to-start-from-new-week-on-year-change) for more details.

```
GROUP BY
DATEDIFF(week, 0, ad.xDate)
```

Thanks to [MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie) for solution.