# How to avoid datepart to start from new week on year change

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an sql query which I am using to get weekly data. It works fine but when the year changes it stops the week on 4 days or whatever and starts a new week for new year. I dont want that. I want it to keep working like like before. Any idea of how to force GROUP BY datepart(week, ad.xDate)

```
Select 'playing' As activity 
,min(ad.xDate) As xDate
,Isnull(sum(t.TimePerDay),0) As TimePerDay 
From    AllDates As ad With (Nolock) 
Left Join @test As t On ad.xDate = t.date
GROUP BY datepart(week, ad.xDate)   
ORDER BY MIN(ad.xDate)
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Why the `NOLOCK` and `MAXRECURSION`?

Comment: Its part of a big query

Comment: Being part of a big query is not a good reason for NOLOCK. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ It is not very clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(week, 0, ad.xDate)
```