# How can I sum values per day and then plot them on calendar from start date to last date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table, part of which is given below. It contain multiple values (durations) per day. I need two things 1) addition of durations per day. 2) plotting them on calendar in such a way that startdate is first_date from the table and last_date is Last_update from the table. I want to mention 0 for which date there is no duration. I think it will something like below but need help.

```
;WITH AllDates AS(
SELECT @Fromdate As TheDate
UNION ALL
SELECT TheDate + 1
FROM   AllDates
WHERE TheDate + 1 <= @ToDate
)SELECT UserId, 
   TheDate,
   COALESCE( 
     SUM(
        -- When the game starts and ends in the same date
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, GameStartTime, GameEndTime) = 0
```

[image]

**Here is what I am looking for** 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to generate the date range you are after would be something like .....

```
;WITH DateLimits AS
 (
    SELECT MIN(First_Date)   FirstDate
          ,MAX(Last_Update) LastDate
    FROM TableName 
 ),
DateRange AS 
(
 SELECT TOP (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,FirstDate,LastDate ) FROM DateLimits)
         DATEADD(DAY
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
              , (SELECT FirstDate FROM DateLimits) 
              ) AS Dates

 FROM master..spt_values a cross join master..spt_values b 
)
SELECT * FROM DateRange   --<-- you have the desired date range here
                             -- other query whatever you need.
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question since I am pretty sure the "other query  whatever you need" is the part he is having trouble with.